# Derivative of the norm of a path

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Let's say $\mathbf c : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is a smooth ($C^\infty$) path where $\mathbf c(t) = \left(c_1(t), c_2(t), \ldots, c_n(t) \right)$.  I think this is how to calculate the derivative of the norm of the path:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Vert\mathbf c(t)\Vert &= \frac{2c_1(t)c_1'(t) + 2c_2(t)c_2'(t) + \cdots + 2c_n(t)c_n'(t)}{2\sqrt{c_1(t)^2 + c_2(t)^2 + \cdots + c_n(t)^2}} \\
&= \frac{\mathbf c(t) \cdot \mathbf c'(t)}{\Vert\mathbf c(t)\Vert},
\end{align}
but I'm not completely sure. Can you please tell me if this is correct and/or if I made any calculation errors?  Thanks!

Comment: You are definitely right. Just a side note: taking norm on both sides and then an application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on RHS yield the interesting result that "derivative of the norm" is "shorter/smaller" than "norm of the derivative".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. In general, the inner product does satisfiy the Leibnitz rule, i.e:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle v(t),v(t)\rangle = \langle \frac{d}{dt} v(t),v(t)\rangle + \langle v(t),\frac{d}{dt} v(t)\rangle=2\langle v(t),\frac{d}{dt} v(t)\rangle$$

Now just note that: $$\frac{d}{dt}\|v(t)\|= \frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\langle v(t),v(t)\rangle}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{{\langle v(t),v(t)\rangle}}}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\langle v(t),v(t)\rangle=\frac{\langle v(t),\frac{d}{dt} v(t)\rangle}{\|v(t)\|}$$

(Note we are assuming $v(t) \neq 0$, the norm is **not** differentiable at the origin)